# Run Angular Tests Scripts From Docker

Tags: angular, docker, testing, npm

We have an angular application that uses jasmine and karma to run tests.  As part of our tests, we get a nice UI browser popup that gives a lot of useful development information.  While this is great for development, and I really want is some way of having a command that gives a result of success or failure for all tests instead.

The purpose of this is to build it into a Dockerfile so we have an easy pass/fail on tests.  For example, one of our services does this:

```
FROM build AS test
WORKDIR /src
COPY Service.Project.Testing/Service.Project.Testing.csproj Service.Project.Testing/
RUN dotnet restore Service.Project.Testing/Service.Project.Testing.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Service.Project.Testing
RUN dotnet test
```

Which for dotnet will cause the docker compose to fail if any of our tests fail, which is desired.  I could do the same thing with npm test instead of dotnet test, but I do not believe we will get a pass/fail on it, as the browser window is created regardless of tests passing or failing.

We have a test script that executes that I believe creates all of that (I was not the implementer, so I'm not certain all of its functionality) but I believe the piece that builds the UI is after the comment "First, initialize the Angular testing environment".  As I mentioned, i do not want to lose this functionality for development, but I want a simple pass/fail for docker compose, similar to how dotnet test works.

```
// Prevent Karma from running prematurely
__karma__.loaded = function () { };

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment
testing.getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  testingBrowser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  testingBrowser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

// Then we find all the tests
const context = require.context('../', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);

// And load the modules
context.keys().map(context);

// Finally, start Karma to run the tests
__karma__.start();
```

Has anyone done this testing before, and is there an easy way of doing it without breaking our nice UI for development?  I imagine it has something to do with an npm run with some kind of similar script to the above, but without the ui components, I just have not been able to get that to function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard practice here is to do a build in Jenkins or whatever you are using. The Jenkins build will look something like this:

(1) clone repo

(2) npm install

(3) ng lint

(4) npm run test:ci (this package.json script should execute the ng test command below)

(5) npm run test:e2e

(6) build docker image with dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.11.3 as node

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/
COPY package-lock.json /app/
RUN npm install --production
COPY ./ /app/
# Are you thinking of running your tests here? Interesting thought! But if you are running npm install with the prod flag (as you should be) your dev dependencies will not be available
RUN npm run build
```

(7) push docker image

(8) ssh into server and update container to use latest image

You are talking about a nice GUI. That's fine you can keep that for dev. For the build you will need a different karma config (a second karma config file).

We have:

karma.conf.js (dev)

karma.conf.ci.js (ci build)

Here's an excerpt from the dev conf:

```
browsers: ['Chrome'],
singleRun: false
```

And an excerpt from the ci build conf:

```
browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
singleRun: true,
customLaunchers: {
  ChromeHeadless: {
    base: 'Chrome',
    flags: [
      '--headless',
      '--disable-gpu',
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--remote-debugging-port=9222'
    ]
  }
}
```

Using headless Chrome for the CI build is important. Its basically, Chrome running in the background without a UI. Not sure how useful the customLaunchers section is but it works for us.

Finally, to start karma using a different config in ng6 the command is:

```
ng test --karma-config karma.conf.ci.js ProjectName
```

I think the command is slightly different in ng5.

Comment: Thanks for the thoroughness of your reply.  I will be testing this out when I get into the office and will update with results.